# Generics and Comparable and Comparator... Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement"

Tags: java, oop, generics, comparator, comparable

This question deals with generics and using the Comparable and Comparator interfaces.

I have a class Chocolate:

```
public class Chocolate implements Comparable<Chocolate> {

    public int compareTo(Chocolate c) {
        if (this.getValue() > c.getValue()) {
            return 1;
        } else if (this.getValue() < c.getValue()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

and a class Pair

```
public abstract class Pair<E extends Comparable<E>, T extends Comparable<T>>
    implements Comparable<Pair<E, T>> { 

    public int compareTo(Pair<E, T> p) {
        if (this.first.compareTo(p.first) > 0) {
            return 1;
        } else if (this.first.compareTo(p.first) < 0) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            if (this.second.compareTo(p.second) > 0) {
                return 1;
            } else if (this.second.compareTo(p.second) < 0) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And another class Sorter with a main method

```
public class SortingClient {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Pair<Chocolate, Chocolate>[] pairs = (Pair<Chocolate, Chocolate>[]) new Pair<?,?>[numPairs];

        Comparator<Pair<Chocolate, Chocolate>> interfaceChocolate = new Comparator<Pair<Chocolate, Chocolate>>(){
            public int compare(Pair<Chocolate,Chocolate> c1, Pair<Chocolate,Chocolate> c2){
                if (c1.compareTo(c2) > 0){
                    return 1;
                }
                else if (c1.compareTo(c2) < 0){
                    return -1;
                }
                else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        } * Error here*
    }
```

I get an *Error* at the second to last line marked saying "Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement" What does this error mean, and how can I fix it?

Comment: u only have to add a semicolon, u have to close your Comparator instantiation even is an annonymus class.. is like variable = new Class(){ //overriding here };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need a semicolon to end a variable declaration, even if you are creating an instance of an anonymous class.

If you had for example a concrete class `PairChocolateComparator`, you would still use a semicolon:

```
Comparator<Pair<Chocolate, Chocolate>> interfaceChocolate =
    new PairChocolateComparator<Pair<Chocolate, Chocolate>>();
```

So you should still add the semicolon for the anonymous class instance:

```
Comparator<Pair<Chocolate, Chocolate>> interfaceChocolate =
    new Comparator<Pair<Chocolate, Chocolate>>(){
         // body omitted
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the semicolon like the message suggests. That is the completion of an assignment statement (to `interfaceChocolate`).

Answer (score 0):

Ya that is Right look at your CODE you have Not used Semi Colleen to Complete Anonymous Class for exmple you Code

```
Comparator<Pair<Chocolate, Chocolate>> interfaceChocolate = new Comparator<Pair<Chocolate, Chocolate>>(){
            public int compare(Pair<Chocolate,Chocolate> c1, Pair<Chocolate,Chocolate> c2){
                if (c1.compareTo(c2) > 0){
                    return 1;
                }
                else if (c1.compareTo(c2) < 0){
                    return -1;
                }
                else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        } * Error here*
```

it should be like this.

```
Comparator<Pair<Chocolate, Chocolate>> interfaceChocolate = new Comparator<Pair<Chocolate, Chocolate>>(){
            public int compare(Pair<Chocolate,Chocolate> c1, Pair<Chocolate,Chocolate> c2){
                if (c1.compareTo(c2) > 0){
                    return 1;
                }
                else if (c1.compareTo(c2) < 0){
                    return -1;
                }
                else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }; * Error here*
```

look at the ; that will finish Class

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error will appear (even when you have a semicolon at the end of your variable declaration) because you have a special character directly below this declaration (such as *) that causes a generic error like this to the line above. Something to look for at least... well, a, say hello to your motha for me, eh